# In a PostgresSQL function, is it possible to check if a column value matches a given parameter value?

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql, stored-functions

In the WHERE clause of a SQL Server stored procedure, I can do this:

```
WHERE (*column_value* = @some_parameter OR @some_parameter IS NULL)
```

When I try to do the same thing in a PostgreSQL function, it throws an error. For example:

```
WHERE(FRQ.QuoteId = p_FilterQuote OR p_FilterQuote IS NULL)
```

produces the error: ***column "p_FilterQuote" does not exist.

The input parameter p_FilterQuote is declared and initialized at the top of the function like this:

```
p_filterquote integer DEFAULT NULL::integer
```

There must be a way to 'use' input parameters in a WHERE clause.

The entire function code is shown below.

```sql
-- FUNCTION: public.postgres_termpositionrawdata_ver3(character varying, date, character, character varying, character varying, character varying, character varying, character varying, integer, integer, character varying, character varying, character varying, character varying, character varying)

-- DROP FUNCTION public.postgres_termpositionrawdata_ver3(character varying, date, character, character varying, character varying, character varying, character varying, character varying, integer, integer, character varying, character varying, character varying, character varying, character varying);

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.postgres_termpositionrawdata_ver3(
    p_provider character varying,
    p_date date,
    p_correlationid character DEFAULT NULL::bpchar,
    p_type character varying DEFAULT NULL::character varying,
    p_productexclusionset character varying DEFAULT 'LevelTermPosition'::character varying,
    p_ctmoptions character varying DEFAULT 'WOM'::character varying,
    p_test character varying DEFAULT 'No'::character varying,
    p_testaccountlogon character varying DEFAULT NULL::character varying,
    p_averagetopx integer DEFAULT 5,
    p_filterquote integer DEFAULT NULL::integer,
    p_includeduplicatequotes character varying DEFAULT 'Yes'::character varying,
    p_ignoreglobalpermissions character varying DEFAULT 'Yes'::character varying,
    p_ignoredefaultproductexclusions character varying DEFAULT 'No'::character varying,
    p_ignorelowstartresponseindicator character varying DEFAULT 'No'::character varying,
    p_ignorevariableresponseindicator character varying DEFAULT 'No'::character varying)
    RETURNS void
    LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'

    COST 100
    VOLATILE 

AS $BODY$

    --DECLARE CONSTANTS
    DECLARE  

    --DECLARE VARIABLES 
 v_Status  varchar(10) = 'Success';BEGIN
  -- assume success

    -- SET CorrelationID
    IF p_CorrelationId IS NULL THEN p_CorrelationId := public.swf_newid();

    END IF; 



         DROP TABLE IF EXISTS FilteredRequests;
         DROP TABLE IF EXISTS FilteredResponses;
         DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Ranks;    




     CREATE TEMP TABLE FilteredRequests AS

        SELECT * FROM public.dblink('srv_exchangemart', '
           SELECT
                 FRQ.QuoteID                    
                ,DEO.Name                                   AS      OrganisationName
                ,DEO.Postcode                               AS      OrganisationPostcode
                ,DEO.FRN                                    AS      OrganisationFRN
                ,DDQ.Date                                   AS      RequestDate
                ,DLB.LifeBasis                          
                ,DDC.Date                                   AS      CommencementDate
                ,DQF.QuotationFor                       
                ,LCR.LifeCriticalIllnessRiskRelationship            
                ,TDP.TotalPermanentDisabilityCover              
                ,CB.CommissionBasis
                ,DCT.CommissionType
                ,DG1.Gender                                 AS      Life1Gender

                FROM FactRequest FRQ    
                INNER JOIN dimExchangeOrganisation DEO ON FRQ.ExchangeOrganisationID = DEO.ExchangeOrganisationId
                INNER JOIN dimExchangeUser DEU ON FRQ.ExchangeUserId = DEU.ExchangeUserId
                INNER JOIN dimLifeBasis DLB ON FRQ.LifeBasisId = DLB.LifeBasisID
                INNER JOIN dimTotalPermanentDisabilityCover TDP ON FRQ.TotalPermanentDisabilityCoverId = TDP.TotalPermanentDisabilityCoverID
                INNER JOIN dimDate DDQ ON FRQ.QuotationDateID = DDQ.DateID
                INNER JOIN dimDate DDC ON FRQ.CommencementDateID = DDC.DateID   
                INNER JOIN dimExchangePanel DEP ON FRQ.ExchangePanelId = DEP.ExchangePanelId            
                INNER JOIN dimCommissionBasis CB    ON FRQ.CommissionBasisId = CB.CommissionBasisId
                INNER JOIN dimCommissionType DCT    ON FRQ.CommissionTypeId = DCT.CommissionTypeId  
                INNER JOIN factClient FC    ON FRQ.QuoteID = FC.QuoteID 
                INNER JOIN dimLifeCriticalIllnessRiskRelationship LCR ON FRQ.LifeCriticalIllnessRiskRelationshipId = LCR.LifeCriticalIllnessRiskRelationshipId
                INNER JOIN dimQuotationFor DQF ON FRQ.QuotationForId = DQF.QuotationForId               
                INNER JOIN dimKeyPerson DKP ON FRQ.KeyPersonId = DKP.KeyPersonId        
                INNER JOIN dimBenefitBasis DBB ON FRQ.BenefitBasisId = DBB.BenefitBasisId       
                INNER JOIN dimIntegrator DI ON FRQ.ExchangeIntegratorId = DI.ExchangeIntegratorId                                                           
                INNER JOIN dimGender DG1    ON FC.Life1GenderID = DG1.GenderID
                INNER JOIN dimGender DG2    ON FC.Life2GenderID = DG2.GenderID                      
                INNER JOIN dimSmoker DS1 ON FC.Life1SmokerID = DS1.SmokerID
                INNER JOIN dimSmoker DS2    ON FC.Life2SmokerID = DS2.SmokerID              
                INNER JOIN dimOccupation DO1    ON FC.Life1OccupationId = DO1.OccupationID
                INNER JOIN dimOccupation DO2    ON FC.Life2OccupationId = DO2.OccupationID  



               WHERE DDQ.Date = p_date
                 AND FRQ.ProductTypeId IN (53)  -- TERM ONLY                 
                 AND DKP.KeyPerson = ''No'' -- Not Business 
                 AND DBB.BenefitBasis = ''Benefit Led'' -- ONLY RETURNS BENEFIT LED QUOTES    

                 AND (DEU.LogonId = p_TestAccountLogon  OR (p_TestAccountLogon IS NULL
                                                        AND DI.DefaultExclusion = ''No''
                                                        AND DEO.DefaultExclusion = ''No''))
                AND (      (p_IncludeDuplicateQuotes = ''No'' AND FRQ.IsDuplicateQuote = 0) 
                        OR (p_IncludeDuplicateQuotes = ''Yes''))
                AND (FRQ.QuoteId = p_FilterQuote OR p_FilterQuote IS NULL)

                AND (   (p_CTMOptions = ''CTM Only''AND DEU.LogonId = ''CTM000'')
                    OR  (p_CTMOptions = ''Exclude CTM'' AND DEU.LogonId != ''CTM000'')
                    OR  (p_CTMOptions = ''WOM'')
                    )
            ')
    AS DATA 
        (QuoteID integer, OrganisationName character varying, OrganisationPostcode character varying, OrganisationFRN character varying, RequestDate date,
                          LifeBasis character varying, CommencementDate date, QuotationCoverFor character varying, 
                          LifeCIRiskRelationship character varying, TPDOption character varying, CommissionBasis character varying, 
                          CommissionType character varying, Life1Gender character varying);

        --  SELECT * FROM FilteredRequests;

        END;
$BODY$;
```

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question and add the **complete** definition of the function. What you are trying to do is certainly possible: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=0c0f5f4404e5c6c99628843424827793

Comment: You are using the parameter inside a string so it's no longer a parameter for that query but a column name (for the "other database")  - you will need dynamic SQL for that. Using a foreign table (through a FDW) will make that **way** easier. Or maybe don't use multiple databases, but use multiple schemas instead, then you don't need this to begin with.

Comment: Ok, I'll read up about Foreign Tables. I already have a Foreign Data Wrapper and a Foreign Server.

Comment: If you are migrating from SQL Server, it's usually better to use schemas instead of databases then you don't need anything like that

Comment: I see. So have all the tables in one database, but use a different schema for the tables that were previously in a different database. I guess that is quite scalable too.

Comment: Correct, due to the architecture of Postgres, using databases as "namespaces" isn't a good choice.

Answer (score 0):

The SQL statement is executed as it is on the remote database, and no parameter substitutions of any kind are performed.

You have to do that yourself:

```
DECLARE
   sql text;
BEGIN
   sql := format(
             'SELECT ... WHERE(FRQ.QuoteId = %L::integer OR %L::integer IS NULL)',
             p_FilterQuote,
             p_FilterQuote
          );
   SELECT * FROM dblink('conn', sql) AS ...;
END;
```